# Splitting string for separate information

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a textbox called `txt_Input` with text that looks as follows:

```
1st. User01 12"80
2nd. User02 12"83
3rd. User03 12"87
4th. User 04 13"03
5th. User0 5 13"10    
etc.
```

I know you can split a string using `string.Split(value)`, however in this example, I am unsure as to how to do so.
I wish to split The Username and time portions into their own variables `name` and `time`. The troubling issue is, however, the username can have spaces.

Removing the ordinal rank is simple by using `str = str.Substring(5);`, which removes everything up to the 1st character of the username (for ranks 0 to 9)

I will be adding these variables to an object in a list, so I am trying to do something to the likes of:

```
private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Competitor> compList;
    for (int i = 0; i < txt_Input.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // Code to separate username and time into varaibles

        Competitor competitor = new Competitor(Username, Time);
        compList.Add(competitor)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but is there a reason you're not just using a unique textbox for each field?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I actually have a section of the program dedicated to exactly that. This is for a "plain text importer" due to some community members using excel spreadsheets. I wish to import their data into my tool, but cannot do so currently without manually entering everything, which is actually a tough task to do.

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin : Not sure to what extent it will help, but you can also spilt it using regex in NotePad++. And put them in separate columns.

Comment: @Koder101 Thanks for the Tim posted an Answer below suggesting Regex. I have never heard of it, so I will look into it now. I might have to do what you said, and maybe, at the least, clean up usernames to remove spacing or something, to create discrete columns

Comment: Since they're using a spreadsheet, can they export it with tab-delimited fields?  Then you can split on '\t' and not have to worry about spaces mucking it up.

Comment: @madreflection I actually don't have access to the spreadsheet.
Basically, it is a tournament style competition, and there are several inputs that go into the ranking, but the output is only rank, username, and time. So, I don't have access to all the other important variables, so I need to take to output, and work backwards, which is the purpose to this. For example, the time in form Ti"me is representative of seconds, which then gets converted back into "frames". This is a really janky feature, but I actually need it to view data I have no direct access to.

Answer (score 1):

You may try splitting each row using a lookahead:

```
string input = "User 04 13\"03";
var items = Regex.Split(input, @"(?=\d{2}""\d{2}$)");
foreach (string item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

User 04 
13"03
```

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. I have never heard of `Regex.Split()`. I will give this a go now. Thank you!

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin Let me know if you have any feedback.